# Is there a way to turn off momentum (inertia) scrolling?

Tags: java, macos, swing

Is there a way to turn off momentum scrolling (scrolling with inertia) in a Java Swing application?

[This guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DriversKernelHardware/RN-MagicMouse/) demonstrates how to do it for a Cocoa application

Adding `"AppleMomentumScrollSupported"` to my `Info.plist` had no effect.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this in a Swing app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this in Java 7, but you need to fork Oracle's [appbundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler) and edit `native/main.m` which compiles into `JavaAppLauncher`:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" 
            forKey:@"AppleMomentumScrollSupported"];
        [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];

        // ...
    }
```